# Disabling Multi-window feature for Android N not working for an activity

Tags: android, multi-window, android-7.0-nougat

I want to disable multi-window support for an activity in my app.
I have set `resizeableActivity` to false in my Manifest but when I long press recent app icon, the app still goes in multi-window mode. Below is my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeV3.CustomToolbar">
</activity>
```

Per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html):

> `android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]`
>
> If the attribute is set to false, the activity does not support multi-window mode. If this value is false, and the user attempts to launch the activity in multi-window mode, the activity takes over the full screen.

I have also tried to set this attribute to false at application level in manifest but it still starts in multi-window mode. Any pointer on what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated?

Comment: This activity does not have an `<intent-filter>`. How is it being started? Is it being started by one of your other activities?

Comment: Hi, Yes its started internally by one of the other activity in the app. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The activity that is at the root of the task controls the window size. Your choices are:

1. Trace back to all possible task root activities in your app and ensure they all also have `android:resizeableActivity="false"`
2. Force this activity into another task, via `Intent` flags when you start it or manifest settings

Comment: Perfect...that fixed it. Thank you so much for your help!!! I had the flag set at application level but that did not work. When I set the flag at the root activity, that did the trick. Wondering why application level flag did not work? Thanks again!!

Comment: @user899849: That attribute is only for `<activity>` and does not appear in [the documentation for `<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).

Comment: It is worth saying that Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is notoriously buggy. So for others encountering this - you probably want to set the taskAffinity for the new activity to something different from the default.
For example:
<manifest
  ...
<application
...
<activity
            android:name="com.example.NoSplitActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:taskAffinity="com.example.NoSplitActivity" />

Comment: @CommonsWare - android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"] attribute is available at <application> level. Your fact is incorrect. I still don't understand what's the point of having an activity specific flag at application level? If mentioned at application level does it apply to all activities?

Comment: @AKh: "android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"] attribute is available at <application> level" -- they added it to the docs sometime after I wrote that comment. "If mentioned at application level does it apply to all activities?" -- yes.

Answer (score 4):

[UPDATE] set android:resizeableActivity="false" in application tag. This will work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet this problem before, and I try many time find that your must 
add android:launchMode="singleTask" && android:resizeableActivity="false"
at the same time.