# Disabling split window android not working in MobileFirst8 platform

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

Trying to disable split-window feature in cordova application, Application works on IBM Mobile First Platform.
Added `android:resizeableActivity="false"` inside manifest `<application>` tag as well as `<activity>` tag

Following error showing.

> \platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:94:
>   AAPT: error: attribute android:resizeableActivity is private.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38528771/4079010) by **CommonsWare**

> From the Answer given

The activity that is at the root of the task controls the window size. Your choices are:

1. Trace back to all possible task root activities in your app and
   ensure they all also have android:resizeableActivity="false"
2. Force this activity into another task, via Intent flags when you
       start it or manifest settings

Comment: Thanks. How to do this "Force this activity into another task, via Intent flags when you start it or manifest settings" ?

Comment: use intent flag for this. `Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Comment: @Sanju have you checked as i told?

Comment: my application is cordova based. I added same code i.e. android:resizeableActivity="false" in native app it is working fine. But same is not working with hybrid app. Also I am adding this to MainActivity how can I set intent flag?

Comment: @Sanju i barely know about cordova. If my answer leads you in right direction don't forget to accept and upvote the answer.